# Href (jumping to location in the same page) is not working in conjuction with showing a hidden div

Tags: html, onclick, href

I'm making a text button that opens a hidden div using a java script somewhere in the page, but also jumps to an location using href. The opening of the hidden div works fine but jumping to a location isn't working. I checked that the #footers is working properly with simple test button.

Here is the html code:

```
<a href="#footers" class="class1" 
    onClick="showHide('footers'); return false; location.href='#footers'" 
    title="Klik hier voor meer informatie">
    Meer info
</a>
```

Here is the Java script (just in case):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function showHide(shID) {
    if (document.getElementById(shID)) {
        if (document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display != 'none') {
            document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'block';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'inline';
            document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: The `return false` prevents the default action of navigating to the link; that applies to *anchors* as well.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `return false` from your click handler.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/APuQe/)